# Play inapp billing doesn't return to application

Tags: android, callback, google-play, in-app-billing

I'm running the Dungeons example successfully when testing Google Plays In Application Billing. But when I try to implement it in my application I don't get it to work successfully.

The point of failure is directly after my application has started the Google Play-intent, payment is done and my application should be returned to the onRecive-method in the BillingReciver. But I never get into the onRecive-method...

Below is the relevant part of the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<service android:name="BillingService" />
    <receiver android:name="BillingReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.digitalwebb.vending.billing.IN_APP_NOTIFY" />
            <action android:name="com.digitalwebb.vending.billing.RESPONSE_CODE" />
            <action android:name="com.digitalwebb.vending.billing.PURCHASE_STATE_CHANGED" />                
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

I guess that there is something I'm missing but now after two days of searching I need a someone to get me in the right direction...

Thanks in advance
Roland

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't personally configured the in-app billing myself, but I think you have to use the ANDROID names for the intent filter.

```
<receiver android:name="BillingReceiver">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.android.vending.billing.IN_APP_NOTIFY" />
    <action android:name="com.android.vending.billing.RESPONSE_CODE" />
    <action android:name="com.android.vending.billing.PURCHASE_STATE_CHANGED" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

And not your own custom names.

ie, use `com.android.vending.billing` and not `com.digitalwebb.vending.billing`

Comment: Right. The Market/Play app sends those broadcasts, and the actions are as specified in the reference. You shouldn't change them to use your own package name, otherwise you won't receive the notifications.

Comment: Thank you, thank you!!!! I don't know how many times I have read the manifest without getting it!